# Complex derivative of the function at the point

Tags: c#, visual-studio, derivative

I'm writing a method to find the derivative of a function at a point.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x = 1;
        double dx = 0.000001;
        double rate;
        rate = (((f(x + dx) - f(x)) / dx));            
    }

    static double f(double x)
    {            
        return Math.Cos(x);
        //return 20*x - 5*Math.Pow(x, 2)+8*Math.Pow(x, 5/4);
    }
```

Derivative of simple functions (like sin(x)) is calculated correctly, but a complex function (like **(20*x - 5*Math.Pow(x, 2)+8*Math.Pow(x, 5/4))**) - not true.

Comment: if I remember my calculus correctly then (f+g)' = f' + g' - (i.e. the derivative of the sum is the sum of the derivative) - can you split your complex function into is bits and see which one is not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though the issue is caused by your integer division

```
5 / 4 == 1
5.0 / 4.0 == 1.25
```

Comment: Yeah! It is true, but if i trying another function like (Math.Pow(2*x, 2) + 3 * (Math.Pow(5 - x, (4.0 / 3.0))) - again not true result. My app: ~1.65 but wolfram: -2.3496

Comment: Brackets? You may find it better to add brackets around the components that you expect to get calculated first, it helps readability too

Comment: @amnesiac - `Math.Pow(2*x, 2) + (3 * Math.Pow(5 - x, 4.0 / 3.0))` - Notice bracket before the 3. Note: I'm not sure if this is correct fix, just an example

Comment: Everything works well. It was my mistake. Thanks for the reply and for advice about integer division!

Comment: @amnesiac - No worries, in general, if you start out using one number type, use it for everything in that line/method (i.e in your example use 3.0 instead of 3 etc). Reduces the risk :)

Answer (score 0):

try modifying the term 5/4 to 5/4f.

Comment: [`Math.Pow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses doubles

Comment: Np, it will still work thanks to higher data type implicit casting.